# surpress output of telnet in bash

Tags: linux, bash, telnet, expect

I'm telnetting to a machine via a bash script. Everything works ok except that the output of the telnet session is displayed on the screen. I'd like to know how to suppress this. I can't seem to find the right place to put `/dev/null` in.

I don't want to run `script.sh > /dev/null` as I need to see other output from it.

```
expect <<EOF
set timeout 20
spawn telnet 0.0.0.0
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Trying 0.0.0.0...\r
Connected to 0.0.0.0.\r
Escape character is '^\]'.\r
\r
User name: "
send -- "user\r"
expect -exact "user\r
\r
Password: "
send -- "pass\r"
expect -exact "pass\r
send -- "commands"
send -- "exit\r"
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `expect` man page, the `log_user 0` command can be used to disable logging to stdout. This doesn't change logging to the logfile. Similarly, `log_user 1` can be used to reenable stdout logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *netcat* (`nc`) instead of *telnet*. *Netcat* doesn't have the extra output that *telnet* displays.

Comment: But don't I have to use an extra file for nc?

Comment: @Lurch No. `nc` can be used as a drop-in replacement for telnet. Give it a try.

Comment: i get spawn                                                          nc 0.0.0.0 23
Ã¿Ã»Ã¿Ã»
User name:

Comment: @Lurch Try `nc` outside of `expect` first to make sure you understand what it's doing. Just try it on the command line.